# How to write S-function with variable size of output signal?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I want to write a block, which sends all image files from selected directory.

Images are of different sizes, so output signal size should vary.

Unfortunately I was unable to find a way to change signal size at each step. There are many of undocumented features here, in examples like

```
block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Variable';
```

and

```
block.OutputPort(1).CurrentDimensions = [1 block.InputPort(1).Data];
```

and so on. I was unable to deduce correct way to operate all this stuff yet...

**UPDATE**

For example, this S-function

```
function Test_SF_01(block)
% Level-2 MATLAB file S-Function.

    setup(block);

function setup(block)

    % Register number of ports and parameters
    block.NumInputPorts  = 0;
    block.NumOutputPorts = 1;
    block.NumDialogPrms  = 0;

    % Setup functional port properties to dynamically inherited
    block.SetPreCompOutPortInfoToDynamic;

    % Register the properties of the output port
    block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Variable';
    block.OutputPort(1).SamplingMode   = 'Sample';

    % Register sample times
    %  [-1, 0] : Inherited sample time
    block.SampleTimes = [-1 0];

    % Register methods called at run-time
    block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs', @Outputs);

function Outputs(block)
    block.OutputPort(1).CurrentDimensions =  floor(rand(1,2)*10)+1;
```

causes an error

> Invalid variable dimensions assignment for output port 1 of
>   'Test_01/Level-2 MATLAB S-Function'. The number of variable dimensions
>   is 1. However, the length of the MATLAB array is 2

why?

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/s-functions-using-variable-size-signals.html?

Comment: Yes I cited this example.

Answer (score 2):

The following S-function generates variable dimension signal. They key problem was that initial set of `Dimensions` property defines MAXIMAL values of dimensions, which is absolutely not clear from docs, while error messages are mostly irrelevant.

```
function Test_SF_01(block)
% Level-2 MATLAB file S-Function.

    setup(block);

function setup(block)

    % Register number of ports and parameters
    block.NumInputPorts  = 0;
    block.NumOutputPorts = 1;
    block.NumDialogPrms  = 0;

    % Setup functional port properties to dynamically inherited
    block.SetPreCompOutPortInfoToDynamic;

    % Register the properties of the output port
    block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Variable';
    block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions = [10000 10000];

    block.OutputPort(1).SamplingMode   = 'Sample';

    % Register sample times
    %  [-1, 0] : Inherited sample time
    block.SampleTimes = [-1 0];

    % Register methods called at run-time
    block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs', @Outputs);

function Outputs(block)

     dims = floor(rand(1,2)*10)+1;
     block.OutputPort(1).CurrentDimensions = dims;

     data = rand(dims);
    block.OutputPort(1).Data = data;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you also looked at the following code example from the doc? See [Operations for Variable-Size Signals](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html#br95l88-1).  There's a bit more in there than what you have in your code. Probably best to start from the basic template `msfuntmpl_basic.m` as they do in the doc.

```
function setup(block)
% Register the properties of the output port
block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Variable';
block.RegBlockMethod('SetInputPortDimensionsMode',  @SetInputDimsMode);

function DoPostPropSetup(block)
%Register dependency rules to update current output size of output port a depending on
%input ports b and c
block.AddOutputDimsDependencyRules(a, [b c], @setOutputVarDims);

%Configure output port b to have the same dimensions as input port a
block.InputPortSameDimsAsOutputPort(a,b);

%Configure DWork a to have its size reset when input size changes.
block.DWorkRequireResetForSignalSize(a,true);

function SetInputDimsMode(block, port, dm)
% Set dimension mode
block.InputPort(port).DimensionsMode = dm;
block.OutputPort(port).DimensionsMode = dm;

function setOutputVarDims(block, opIdx, inputIdx)
% Set current (run-time) dimensions of the output
outDimsAfterReset = block.InputPort(inputIdx(1)).CurrentDimensions;
block.OutputPort(opIdx).CurrentDimensions = outDimsAfterReset;
```

Comment: I need to have no input ports, only output. Can you rewrite my way?

Comment: where `a`, `b` and `c` are defined in your example? where are `SetInputPortDimensionsMode` and `AddOutputDimsDependencyRules` methods are documented? I see no `SetOutputPortDimensionsMode` method.

Comment: I think `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are defined in the basic template `msfuntmpl_basic.m`, which I believe you can access by typing `sfundemos` at the command line. For the rest, see:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/sfg/setinputportdimensionsmode.html. It looks like `AddOutputDimsDependencyRules` is not documented, you way want to ask MathWorks about that. I think you are correct about `SetOutputPortDimensionsMode`.

Comment: This thread also my be of use:
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/45715-hi-everybody-i-got-one-problem-when-using-s-function-dynamic-output-the-input-dimensions-of-my-s