# How to write a S-function, generating signal of higher than 2 dimensions?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink

Apparently, I am unable to generate a signal of [3x3x3] dimensions:

```
function Test_SF_02(block)
% Level-2 MATLAB file S-Function.

    setup(block);

function setup(block)

    % Register number of ports and parameters
    block.NumInputPorts  = 0;
    block.NumOutputPorts = 1;
    block.NumDialogPrms  = 0;

    % Setup functional port properties to dynamically inherited
    block.SetPreCompOutPortInfoToDynamic;

    % Register the properties of the output port
    block.OutputPort(1).SamplingMode   = 'Sample';
    %block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Variable';
    block.OutputPort(1).DimensionsMode = 'Fixed';
    block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions = [3 3 3];



    % Register sample times
    %  [-1, 0] : Inherited sample time
    block.SampleTimes = [-1 0];

    % Register methods called at run-time
    block.RegBlockMethod('Outputs', @Outputs);


function Outputs(block)

    block.OutputPort(1).Data = zeros(3,3,3);
```

error occurs at `block.OutputPort(1).Dimensions` assignment and says

> Cannot set dimensions of output port 1 of 'Test_01/Level-2 MATLAB
>   S-Function' to [3x3x3]. This block is not setup to handle signals of
>   dimensions greater than 2 dimensions.

Why? I saw blocks, generating image frames, i.e. `MxNx3` matrices.

**UPDATE**

This is not duplicate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write S-function with variable size of output signal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17703376/how-to-write-s-function-with-variable-size-of-output-signal)

Comment: The "possible duplicate" linked above is a question about having a signal that can vary in size at each time step (i.e. be a 10 element vectors at time t0, then an 8 element vector at time t1, then an n element vector at time tn).  It has nothing to do with 3D matrices, which is the topic of this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the setup method you need to use the method

```
block.AllowSignalsWithMoreThan2D = 1;
```

This would typically be done immediately after the number of inputs, outputs and parameters are defined.

Note also that being a source block, Simulink would prefer you to specify its sample time, not have it back inherited.